# WCF Service on IIS - vdpoledb 'Inavlid Path or File Name'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-foxpro, foxpro

tried everything to get this working I can only guess its a permissions issue when I am trying to update the table.

This works fine on my dev pc and updates the table fine.

However when hosting the wcf web service on our IIS server and I invoke a method within the web service I am getting error 'Invalid Path Or File Name'.

I have put in my main app web config:

```
<identity impersonate="true"
   userName="domain\user"
   password="password"/>
```

But it is still not working. My web.config for the webservice project is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="GeoLocation.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="GeoLocation.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="GeoLocation.IService1">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GeoLocation.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I know my connection string is correct as it works on my dev pc. I am using VFPOLEDB.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: From what I remember, the connection should be "VFPOLEDB.1".  Anyhow, not seeing your insert/update command you are trying to execute.  As for correct connection string, can't confirm that either... are you connecting to the PATH where the data IS, or connecting directly to the table... you should ONLY be connecting to the PATH.  Additionally, it may be the USER does not have read/write permissions to the path and/or files.

Comment: Hi I have fixed this now, it was a permissions issue thanks